# Trouble getting biblatex-apa to display multiple authors as last-first/first-last

Tags: biblatex

`biblatex-apa` displays the author names for papers with multiple authors like this:

```
Thomason, Sarah and Everett, Dan
```

but I need it to be displayed like this:

```
Thomason, Sarah and Dan Everett.
```

I have tried what seems to be prescribed elsewhere, adding `\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first/first-last}` to my preamble, but have seen no change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `apa` biblatex sytle defines its own directives for name formats. In  particular it defined `apaauthor` (which is the default format), thus, to achieve the desired effect one has to change `apaauthor`, namely:

```
\DeclareNameAlias{apaauthor}{last-first/first-last}
```